# How do a see the "ancestor tree" of a docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm diagnosing some caching issues with a large docker compose file and I'd like to make sure that all my images have common `FROM`s to make sure I'm not downloading too many base images.

Right now I'm using `docker history` to look at the parents, but what I'd really like is a command like:

```
$ docker-compose tree
centos:123
  |-> elasticsearch
  |-> postgres
alpine-java:456
  |-> my-service
```

For a docker compose file that contained images for `elasticsearch`, `postgres`, `myservice`

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: I am unaware of such a toll, but you can use Dockerfile from image from https://github.com/CenturyLinkLabs/dockerfile-from-image and look at the `FROM` line in the result